# Spyder ide : surround a selected code block in try except clause

Tags: python, spyder

In spyder-ide do we have a feature to put a try except clause around a selected code block. Say we select some lines of code and put them within a auto generated try except clauses where in we just need to add the except clauses as per our need.

Spyder ide documentation dosent seem to be mentioning this.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/spyderlib. : you can try here

Answer (score 0):

Spyder-ide seems to be not having feature to surround selected code block in try/except clause.

I had raised the question in spyder-ide github repo [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/14573) is what the maintainers have to say.They have marked it as a feature that *may be* implemented in future.